# No such signal QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I am trying to handle sslErrors in custom class WebPage inherited from QWebPage.

```
WebPage::WebPage()
{
    connect(
        networkAccessManager(),
        SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),
        this,
        SLOT(handleSslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));
}
```

But have a runtime error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Was your Qt compiled with SSL support ?

Comment: No, after recompiling it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to recompile Qt with SSL support, in my case using OpenSSL:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -icu -I C:\ICU\include -L C:\ICU\lib -openssl -I C:\openssl\include -L C:\openssl\lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (modificators like `const` and reference `&` should be omitted):

```
WebPage::WebPage()
{
    connect(
        networkAccessManager(),
        SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)),
        this,
        SLOT(handleSslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));
}
```

If you are using Qt Creator it should help you properly autocomplete this.